# Rails 3.1 Images Broken in Stylesheets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, sass, erb, asset-pipeline

I've been running a small application that I originally wrote under Rails 3.1.0.rc4. Last night I began the transition to 3.1.0 final. Well I hit a frustrating snag in the asset pipeline. My js is fine, my css is fine; however, images included on stylesheets are NOT fine. I'm using .css.scss.erb extensions so that I can use both SASS and the asset_path helper to provide paths to my compiled assets.

example:

```
background: url(<%= asset_path "background.png" %>);
```

results in:

```
background: url('background.png');
```

which is a problem since the compiled asset is background-a76dde63a16fbb15fe1b4ec496b50877.png

Both image_tag and asset_path work correctly in erb views in the application, but not in the scss files. Any input would be very welcome.

Comment: dose your application.rb has `config.assets.enabled = true`

Answer (score 2):

If you change your `.css` file to `.scss` you can use the `_url` and `_path` helpers that **sass-rails** provides:

`background: image_url("background.png")` will get picked up and "fingerprinted" in production.

[More Info](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets)

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I've used that helper, but I generally just hardcode

```
url(/assets/image.jpg);
```